# capture output using expect

Tags: shell, expect

I want compare the number of files on the remote server and my local directory. I ssh into the server and I was able to capture the output of "ls somewhere/*something | wc -l" using $expect_out(buffer) and store it as a variable. Now my problem is that how do I come back to my local computer and count the files here and compare them. After this comparison, I need to go back to the server and continue the job if the result of the comparison is acceptable.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use `expect` for this?

Comment: I want to automate this process. Go to the server -> do the job -> come back check something -> go back in and repeat. I thought expect is the tool here, right?

Comment: Not necessarily. You could use a bash coprocess for the job, or just a single SSH session with ControlMaster functionality holding the transport open while running several separate commands over that transport.

Comment: (See https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/Multiplexing re: background on ControlMaster/ControlSocket; basically, it provides a mechanism to run multiple distinct SSH commands over the same connection without needing to authenticate and handshake more than once).

Comment: BTW, `ls | wc` is not an ideal way to count files -- depending on the system you run it on, filenames with newlines (yes, they're legal) can be double-counted. Do you know the platform? If you're guaranteed to have GNU `find` available, you can use `find /path -printf '.\n'` or such, such that the output *only* correlates with the number of files and not what their names are. Also see [BashFAQ #4](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/004) for other suggestions/guidance on counting files without `ls`, and [ParsingLs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: Would this ControlMaster work if the SSH session is not allowed to last very long? This server I work on has issues. It will cut u off once a while.

Comment: If it's an idle timeout, not so hard to be sure you're doing keepalive from the client side -- various mechanisms, depending on exactly which layer (ie. if it's TCP keepalive vs sshd config) is cutting you off.

Comment: I see your point. I am not a pro programmer. My job here is  to download tons() of data for my research. It takes months to download them, so the i am aware of the fact ls and wc are not the best. but as long as they work i dont really care how long it takes them to run.

Comment: If you're trying to transfer a lot of data, the usual tool for the job (which supports ignoring content when files exist with the same timestamps, which I assume is what you're trying to do here) is `rsync`. I assume you've considered it?

Comment: I am using scp. I just googled rsync it seems to be good too. I still want to know how to compare files numbers on the server and files numbers on the local disk.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do -- including from a correctness perspective -- is to not try to have a single long-running SSH session, but multiple shorter-lived ones (potentially using [SSH multiplexing](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/Multiplexing) to reuse a single transport between such sessions):

```
count_remote_files() {
  local host=$1 dirname=$2 dirname_q
  printf -v dirname_q '%q' "$dirname"
  remote_files=$(ssh "$host" "bash -s ${dirname_q}" <<EOF
    cd "$1" || exit
    set -- *
    if [ "$#" -eq 1 ] && [ ! -e "$1" ] && [ ! -L "$1" ]; then
      echo "0"
    else
      echo "$#"
    fi
EOF
  )
}

count_local_files() {
  local dirname=$1
  cd "$dirname" || return
  set -- *
  if [ "$#" -eq 1 ] && [ ! -e "$1" ] && [ ! -L "$1" ]; then
    echo "0"
  else
    echo "$#"
  fi
}

if (( $(count_remote_files "$host" "$remote_dir") ==
      $(count_local_files "$local_dir") )); then
  echo "File count is identical"
else
  echo "File count differs"
  ssh "$host" 'echo "doing something else now"'
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Expect, you can easily count the local files by using Tcl commands, since Expect is built on top of Tcl:

```
set num_local_files [llength [glob somewhere/*something]]
```

For more info see http://nikit.tcl.tk/page/Tcl+Tutorial+Lesson+25